# How would I create a new column containing an index of column in sqlite database Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

Say I have a table with one column called name and each row with one observation.

```
 NAME
('John Smith')
('Paul Smith')
('Jake Smith')
```

How would I modify the table so it contains an index of each row to get something like below. I need to use standard Python packages only.

```
 NAME               INDEX
('John Smith')        1
('Paul Smith')        2
('Jake Smith')        3



con = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cur = con.cursor()
table= "CREATE TABLE names(name TEXT)"
cur.execute(table)

INSERT INTO names(name)
VALUES ('John Smith');
VALUES ('Paul Smith');
VALUES ('Jake Smith');
```

Comment: what format is the table in? like what data type is it stored in?

Comment: I should have specified, but its in sqlite database as a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite creates a hidden column called "ROWID" that does this automatically.

```
sqlite> create table names(id TEXT);
sqlite> insert into names values ('John Smith'),('Paul Smith'),('Jake Smith');
sqlite> select rowid, id from names;
1|John Smith
2|Paul Smith
3|Jake Smith
sqlite> ALTER TABLE names ADD COLUMN names_index INTEGER;
sqlite> UPDATE names SET names_index=rowid;
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT * FROM names;
┌────────────┬─────────────┐
│     id     │ names_index │
├────────────┼─────────────┤
│ John Smith │ 1           │
│ Paul Smith │ 2           │
│ Jake Smith │ 3           │
└────────────┴─────────────┘
sqlite>
```

If you create your own column that is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it will be used as the ROWID.

Comment: I see that is helpful. For my purposes I do need the rowid as a seperate column called names_index. Is there a way to take that hidden column and make it as an actual column?

Comment: `UPDATE names SET names_index=rowid`, assuming the `names_index` field already exists.  That won't be updated as new rows are added.  Really, if you need an index field, you should be adding the index field yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to SQL in general. In my case, the names_index field won't already exist. There is one field which is names, and my question is how I can add the index column and ultimately create hew new field in sqlite

Comment: `ALTER TABLE names ADD COLUMN names_index INTEGER`